# Community Wiki URL

Tags: discussion

On various answers I have read references that "this would be a good addition to the Community Wiki". However, I have searched but have not been able to find the URL for the wiki referenced. Could someone share the URL, and could there be a menu or sidebar link to the Community Wiki so we can see what it contains?

I presume the reference is to a wiki that relates to "Graphic Design". If this is not the right place for this question, please help find the correct location.

UPDATE:

The most obvious place where "Community Wiki" appears is below the edit window when writing an answer with a check box next to it. Clicking in it produces a modal window with a question  "are you sure you want to make this a community wiki post." If it is no longer in use, that option may need to be eliminated from the edit window.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/255554

Comment: Could you link where you see that comment? I could imagine a comment saying, "This might be better as a Community Wiki" but never "better ADDITION to the Community Wiki" as that would make no sense. There is no "Wikipedia style wiki."

Comment: @Ryan you may be correct about the wording, I wrote from the memory which at my age is more likely to be fallible. It was, however, in one of my comment exchanges on a question or an answer.

Comment: @Ryan, I am not sure if updated questions or answers trigger a new message alert, so I am adding this in case...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no single collective "Community Wiki". Individual Questions or Answers can be converted to a Community Wiki (CW), but that functionality is largely obsolete.

CWs were previously beneficial because they allowed anyone to make an edit to the post regardless of their reputation. The implementation of suggested edits axed that benefit; now even anonymous users can make an edit.

The only time they are useful now is if you'd like to make a post where you want to encourage others to collaborate on an answer. [Here's a good example of that](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/26355/8708).

Comment: I don't even know - is there a way to filter to Community-Wiki's quickly? Perhaps we should create a Wiki tag otherwise to facilitate in that.

Comment: @Ryan search for "[wiki:yes](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=wiki%3Ayes)"

Comment: I did find a tag for "Community Wiki" among the tags which did not bring me to the mother lode. Perhaps I read too much into a reply to a comment which made a reference to the community wiki. I will stop searching for it now!

Comment: An additional thought, I see some visitors asking a question and then not coming back to provide answers to simple comments to complete the answering process. I waited for an answer from such a user for whom I may have several good possible solutions. I am not sure if posting it as an answer will serve much of the community. It would be nice if there were an option to provide such an answer as a separate body of collections. I thought that was the purpose of a wiki, thus my search.

Comment: The most obvious place where "Community Wiki" appears is below the edit window when writing an answer with a check box next to it. Clicking in it produces a modal window with a question  "are you sure you want to make this a community wiki post." If it is no longer in use, that option may need to be eliminated from the edit window.

Comment: @ACEkin it does still have _some_ use, we just don't really use it on Graphic Design. It's useful to encourage collaboration to create a definitive answer, usually to a frequently asked question

Comment: It is also useful if someone wishes to write an answer—or question—without being personally associated with it (including receiving or losing points for up- and downvotes). Community Wiki posts are ‘owned’ by the community, rather than the individual user, so it’s basically disassociating yourself from a posting. (And as I recently discovered, suggested edits here on Meta require 3,000 rep points, so there it also serves its former purpose of allowing all registered users to edit posts.)